# Boost.Build get Compiler command

Tags: c++, boost, boost-build, bjam

I'm trying to add support for embedded devices to boost.build. For that I need two additional commands `arm-none-eabi-objcopy` and `arm-none-eabi-size`. Since the toolchain can change I would need to get those two commands (and not hardcode them), without changing the library.

Is there a way to get the `arm-none-eabi-g++` command so I can deduce the commands from this?

Comment: What do you mean "deduce the commands"? What do you want to do?

Comment: I want to get the literal command called to compile to deduce the prefix, so  I can construct the command needed. So I can also get "msp-none-eabi-objcopy" if the compiler command is "msp-none-eabi-g++".

And I did see the other question, but I need it inside the jam-files.